# Error importing SQL Azure Bacpac to SQL Server 2014 LocalDb

Tags: azure-sql-database, sql-server-localdb

Downloaded a v12 SQL Azure bacpac, and trying to import it into a SQL Server 2014 LocalDB... I get:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Could not load schema model from package. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Internal Error. The database platform service with type     Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid.     You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

I have tried installing the Data-Tier Framework Jan 2016 Preview which did not make any difference (both x64 and x86).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution is pretty simple, you need to ensue you have sql Server 2014 sp1 installed. can't believe I missed that!